# Process to georeference corners of vector file

Tags: qgis, vector, georeferencing

In QGIS I trying to wrap my arms around it so please bear with me.

I have vector files (DXF) that I need to add back in the georeferencing. They were edited with Illustrator so I loose all georeferencing when saved as a .DXF. Now I have matching images where I have the corner coordinates.  I would like to use those to put back into the dxf. Is this possible?

I am still reading up on QGIS but have not for a process other that "pixel-point" type referencing which will not work for my needs.

Is there a Plugin perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Since the 1.10 version of GDAL/OGR, you can now "georeference" vectors layers ([Add ability to transform vectors based on GCPs in ogr2ogr](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4604)) with translations, rotations and shearing

```
ogr2ogr -gcp 5 -135 0 0 \
     -gcp 283 -135 1000 0 \
     -gcp 5 278 0 1000 \
     -gcp 283 278 1000 1000 \
     -f "ESRI shapefile" gcppolyg2.shp gcppolyg.shp
```

[image]
[image]

This feature has been implemented in QGIS in a Processing/Toolbox script and two new plugins.

- [PortailSIG: QGIS 2 - script to georeference vectors (in French)](https://portailsig.org/content/qgis-2-script-et-methode-pour-faire-du-georeferencement-vectoriel.html) using `ogr2ogr` with the `subprocess`Python module
- [Plugin: vector Georef](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/vectGeoref/)
- [Plugin: vector Bender](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VectorBender/)