# Georeferencer equivalent for vectors

Tags: georeferencing, wmts

I'm digitising historic maps for an area about 2km square using QGIS 3.18 (the maps are from the David Rumsey maps collection, using WMTS).

Once I have the digitised maps (in polygons representing roads, field boundaries and buildings), I'd like to effectively do the same as I would with a raster map, and use georeferencer to rubberband the digitised map and align various features to produce maps that are overlaid on each other.

I'd have started by using georeferencer first if the maps were available in a format that would allow georeferencing - but I dont see how to convert WMTS output into a form suitable for this.

Has anyone any ideas if the equivalent of the georeferencer process could be done in any way with vector layers?

Comment: With ogr see [Process to georeference corners of vector file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/107303/2581)

Comment: If you digitize new vector data on top of WMTS imagery you get georeferenced data by the same if you just attach the CRS of your project to the new layer. But perhaps I do not understand your workflow.

Comment: can you give an example of the maps you are digitising from?

Comment: Thanks gene - that's the answer I was looking for.